# Adding selected and disabled attributes to an option tag in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm trying to debug some code that doesn't display properly. The code should add a default option to an drop down list that is disabled from selection. What I get is that the list option is displayed but not selected by default. After the page is loaded I inspect element on that list box and I am shown the following html for the first item of the list:

```
<option value="" disabled="">
```

When I select edit as HTML the tag expands to

```
<option value="" disabled="" selected="">
```

By simply creating a local html file using the tag with `selected=""` I can get the desired results but I'm not sure why it doesn't appear in the inspector until I select edit as HTML.

Here is the rest of the code pertaining to this issue:

```
<div class='input-block smallish' id="inquiry-type">
  <span class='label'>
    Inquiry Type <span>(required)</span>
  </span>
  <div>
    <select class="default xl" id="ticket_custom1" name="ticket[custom1]">
    <option value="Problem Report">Problem Report</option>
    <option value="Usage or Technical Question">Usage or Technical Question</option>
    <option value="Enhancement Request">Enhancement Request</option>
    <option value="New Project Idea">New Project Idea</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option></select>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    ...
    // Add our default for lists
    $('.input-block:not(.disable-default) select').prepend('<option value="" disabled selected>-- Select one --</option>');
    ...
</script>
```

There are more scripts but I don't think they pertain to this error. Also I get the desired results in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There definitely does appear to be a difference between Internet Explorer and Chrome/Firefox. That being said, you can avoid this issue by explicitly setting the `selectedIndex` of the element itself:

```
$( "select" ).prop( "selectedIndex", 0 );
```

I'll file an Interop bug internally on this to have our team look into the issue and make a determination as to what the appropriate behavior should be.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qtcs1kxe/1/
Feature Test: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/ub1yt4vv/show

Comment: This solution solved my problem but your feature test passes in Chrome but fails in IE.

Comment: The test passes in Chrome because Chrome does what we *expect* it to do. Internet Explorer presently fails because it *does not* do what we expect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess IE11 doesn't notice the `selected` attribute when you're appending after rendering.

You'll need to select the option in your script. Just add `val('')` to the end of your prepend. Works for me.

```
$('.input-block:not(.disable-default) select').prepend('<option value="" disabled selected>-- Select one --</option>').val('');
```